# Programmatically add more than one taxonomy term in Drupal 7

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

Just a quick question. I'm creating a node and adding a term to the node like this:

```
 $newNode->field_tags[$newNode->language][]['tid'] = "a digit here";
```

Fine, but how do I add more than one term per node? I've tried a comma-separated string of digits and an array of digits but neither work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just keep adding to the array the way you're already doing:

```
$newNode->field_tags[$newNode->language][]['tid'] = "a digit here";
$newNode->field_tags[$newNode->language][]['tid'] = "another digit here";
```

Or you could loop instead:

```
$tids = array(1, 2, 3);
foreach ($tids as $tid) {
  $newNode->field_tags[$newNode->language][]['tid'] = $tid;
}
```